# How can I use a keyboard shortcut to switch focus to another display?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager

I looked at this question - [Keyboard shortcut to switch focus between multiple displays on OS X 10.9+](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-focus-between-multiple-displays-on-os-x-10-9) -  but the op doesn't seem to have the same goal as me.

I have a multi-monitor setup, and I have [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) set up to only show windows on my current desktop *and* on my current monitor. This is how I want AltTab to work since I have a lot of windows open.

However, I also want a way to switch my focus to another **monitor** using a keyboard shortcut. For example, I want <kbd>Ctrl + ⌘ + →</kbd> to focus the top-most window on the monitor to the right without having to move my mouse.

Is there an app that can handle this? I'm aware of Keyboard Maestro, but am hoping to find a free option. If there is a way to do this with a custom script (python, js, or similar) I'm open to that as well.

Comment: You can't "shift focus to another monitor" because you are moving along the same *extended* desktop.  When you move between monitors the mouse X/Y coordinate just extends - it doesn't identify it by which monitor.  When you shift focus, you focus on a Window, not a display.

Comment: While my overall goal is to shift focus to another display, I explained in my original question that this would likely be done by focusing the top-most window on a given display. My question is asking about a way to bind that action to a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amethyst has this functionality (and much more to move windows around your screen). It is free, open-source and actively worked on (as of 2023). [Here is the repo link](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst)

With the default config, the 2 shortcuts your are looking for are:

- `mod1 + p` Move focus to counter clockwise screen
- `mod1 + n` Move focus to clockwise screen

`mod1` is by default `option + shift`

**WARNING**
Make sure to read throughly the documentation before installing/starting it. A lot of features you might not want (e.g. window tiling, or some layouts) will be enabled  by default and might annoy you.

---

**BONUS**
The shortcuts I use (this might give you some ideas)

1. Configured through karabiner (i.e. [link to the modification used](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#option_pgup_pgdown_home_end_to_ctrl_arrows)) but can be done through `Systems Preferences` (i.e. [reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213549/keyboard-shortcuts-for-switching-spaces))

   - `CTRL + OPTION + SHIFT + H` Mission control, move to left space on focused screen
   - `CTRL + OPTION + SHIFT + L` Mission control, move to right space on focused screen
2. Configured through Amethyst

   - `OPTION + SHIFT + H` Move focus to counter clockwise screen
   - `OPTION + SHIFT + L` Move focus to clockwise screen
   - `OPTION + SHIFT + J` Move focus to next window on focused screen
   - `OPTION + SHIFT + K` Move focus to previous window on focused screen

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for. Appreciate the bonus shortcuts as well.